# Redirect stopped working

Tags: php

I created a basic login script in php. on my lampp localhost the redirects work fine. when I load the template to another server the redirects dont work anymore. Can anyone tell me why this is and how to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here is the script for admin.php which holds a login form. if `$_SESSION['logged_in']` is set then the user should be redirected to the backend.php page every time. But on the server it keeps showing the admin.php page every time. but again when I am on my lampp localhost it works fine.

```
$users = new Users;

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) === true) {
    header('Location: backend.php');
} else {
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'All fields are required!';
        } else {
            $login = $users->login($username, $password);

            if ($login == 0) {
                $errors[] = 'Username or password incorrect!';
            } else {
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                header('Location: backend.php');
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `<?php session_start(); ?>` ?

Comment: You should also `exit()` after the first `header()` call.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid the `session_start` is in a file that is included within the file above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the rest of the file contains the actual HTML of the admin page?

Have you verified that the `if` is getting into the branch you expect. By either using a debugger or something more primitive like `die('This should redirect!');`

If you have, then the problem is most likely that you have output occurring before your `header` call. Make sure all errors are showing. It should give you an error telling where the problem is.

It is because of this, it is common to `exit()` after a header redirect call - to prevent the rest of the page being inadvertently run/displayed.

Comment: I now have `exit()` after both header redirects. and error reporting is on but is not giving me anything. All it does is when i make it redirect it exits and blanks the screen but does not go to the page. It just stays on the same one

Comment: So, the `if` is working, but the header redirect is not. It still sounds like there is some output before the header call. Even a single space character at the end of a previous include is enough to stop it working. Make sure there are no spaces/newlines after your closing php tags (`?>`) and make sure error_reporting is set to E_ALL and display_errors is on.

Comment: after putting error reporting to E_ALL i had to move the head.php include down below the script because it was outputing and after I did that I worked :)

Answer (score 0):

use `<?php session_start(); ?>` begin of the code.

Comment: that is placed in another file that is included within the one above

Comment: is `<?php session_start(); ?>` in function in anouther file?

Answer (score 0):

Your server likely has a different root folder than your local does. I would try

```
<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]; ?>
```

and also

```
<?php echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] ?>
```

That will tell you for sure where you should be.